# Printing SVGs from Chrome

Tags: printing, svg

I have an interactive application which produces output as a series of 8.5x11 SVG files (each file is meant to be correspond to a single page). This SVG is displayed in Chrome (my web browser.)

I currently don't have routines to convert this SVG to either postscript or pdf. All I want is to be able to print out the SVGs.

Question:

What is the best approach for doing this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'd prefer to not have any borders of any sort, and print out the 8.5x11 svg "literally" on to paper, without any 'decorations' of any sort.

Comment: Can you clarify this a little more? What prevents you from using Ctrl+P?

Comment: I'd prefer to not have any borders of any sort, and print out the 8.5x11 svg "literally" on to paper, without any 'decorations' of any sort.

Comment: @ThomasW : Great clarification question. Thanks!

Comment: Then, why are you using your browser instead of e.g. Inkscape or an image viewer that supports SVG?

Comment: @ThomasW: It's a server side application that renders to a SVG inside of a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print dialog in Chrome has a "Margins" setting. If you select "None" it will print the SVG File as-is without page numbering or extraneous elements.

If by *decorations* you mean the rest of dom elements of the page, you can right click the SVG and "Open Image in New Tab" and print from there.